# TypeError: Object.setPrototypeOf called on null or undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I have a Node.js project in which I have my own custom error:

```
'use strict';

require('util').inherits(module.exports, Error);

function CustomError(message, extra) {
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  this.name = this.constructor.name;
  this.type = 'CustomError';
  this.message = message;
  this.extra = extra;
};

module.exports = CustomError;
```

This used to work fine. I could `Throw new CustomError('my message', dataObject)` and capture that error independently of offer error types and control the program flow accordingly.

However, since updating Node to the latest stable release (v6.4.0) it's now broken. When I run my unit tests I get the error:

```
TypeError: Object.setPrototypeOf called on null or undefined
    at Function.setPrototypeOf (native)
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:973:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (CustomError.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> require('util').inherits(module.exports, Error);
> module.exports = CustomError;
> ```

Clearly `module.exports` is an empty object with an `undefined` `.prototype` in the first line. You need to call `inherits` *after* you create the constructor function! Move the line down, or use

```
require('util').inherits(CustomError, Error);
```

which would work even in the top because the function declaration is hoisted.

> This used to work fine.

Not exactly, but it did not throw an error [before node v6](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/29da8cf8d7ab8f66b9091ab22664067d4468461e).

Comment: `module.exports === exports === {}`, it is not `undefined` by default.

Comment: @mscdex right, fixed. `setPrototypeOf` isn't called on it directly

Comment: That seems really obvious now it's pointed out to me! I'm still a little confused as to how it could ever have worked. I was starting to question if the code had changed, but git history says otherwise and it's currently running in production with an older version of Node.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as I was upgrading Node to try out some ES6 niceties, I thought I'd refactor to extend the class in a more modern way:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = class CustomError extends Error{
    constructor (message, extra){
          super(message);
          this.name = this.constructor.name;
          this.type = 'CustomError';
          this.extra = extra;
    }
}
```

I think this is a better long-term fix, though @Bergi seems to have answered the question that was asked.